# Who was first in precedence inside the House?

Tags: keys-to-the-kingdom

In Sir Thursday we find:

> ‘I do beg your pardon, ma’am,’ said the lieutenant. ‘Crosshaw is my name, recruiting officer. I have a draft requisition for one Arthur Penhaligon, only I think there must be a mistake, as it gives this Arthur a precedence within the House of … well … six. I thought perhaps there might be a large number of zeroes missing. Perhaps if there is someone among Mister Monday’s staff called Arthur Penhaligon, I might test the draft document?’
>
> ‘There is no mistake,’ said Dame Primus. She indicated Arthur with a lofty wave of her hand. ‘The person in question is Lord Arthur Penhaligon, Master of the Lower House, Lord of the Far Reaches, Duke of the Border Sea, sixth in precedence within the House. I am Dame Primus, Parts One, Two, and Three of the Will of the Architect.’

How is Arthur only sixth? There's Sir Thursday, Lady Friday, Superior Saturday and Lord Sunday, leaving Arthur fifth.

If you count the Piper, the Old One and The Mariner he should be lower down in precedence.

So how is Arthur only sixth? And who is the missing one?

Answer (score 2):

**The Architect.**

There's really only one option for someone who would be at the top of the hierarchy, or anywhere else in it. The Piper and the Mariner aren't part of the House hierarchy, since they were a consequence of some of the Architect's experiments with mortality. The Old One almost certainly counts as just another part of the Architect, or perhaps has no rank, being imprisoned. It's also plausible that this refers to Dame Primus, whose name, after all, signifies that she is the first, and who is the largest part of the Architect who's still free.

This, of course,  is an early hint that the Architect is not entirely dead.

Comment: I think that the fact that Dame Primus constantly subjugates herself to Arthur implies that she is lower in command.

Comment: Recall that House precedence does not grant any power over others. Saturday can attempt to defy Sunday despite his higher rank. Dame Primus is not obligated to obey Arthur or act lower than him; she does so in order to manipulate him into bringing about her goal. And in fact being the Architect I doubt she considers herself lesser